# LinearPercentIndicator not working ( The method 'LinearPercentIndicator' isn't defined for the type )

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have installed `percent_indicator` package version 4.2.2 in the first place and everything worked as expected. After a while, without doing anything, for some reason i started receiving an error on `LinearPercentIndicator` widget stating that

`The method 'LinearPercentIndicator' isn't defined for the type '_MatchDetailsPageState'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'LinearPercentIndicator'.`

The import is correct if it looks like this:

`import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';`

but if i'm going to make it more specific, it throws an error as well:

`import 'package:percent_indicator/linear_percent_indicator.dart';`

which leads to -> `Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:percent_indicator/linear_percent_indicator.dart'.`

I tried using an older version of the package, cleaning the solution, getting all packages again, upgrading the packages, upgrading flutter, but none of this worked.

I don't think the source code file is needed, but if it is i can add it anytime.

Later UPDATE:

the pubspec.yaml file :

```
name: livescore
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  day_night_switcher: ^0.2.0+1
  provider: ^6.0.3
  spring: ^2.0.2
  flutter_icon_shadow: ^2.0.6
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  flutter_bounceable: ^1.0.3
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  easy_loader: ^2.0.0
  widget_loading: ^0.3.2
  loading_animations: ^2.2.0
  loading_indicator: ^3.1.0
  collection: ^1.16.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

the file that is throwing the error:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/linear_percent_indicator.dart';

class MatchDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MatchDetailsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MatchDetailsPage> createState() => _MatchDetailsPageState();
}

class _MatchDetailsPageState extends State<MatchDetailsPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 10, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, width: 5),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 220,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(55, 0, 60, 0.3),
                            spreadRadius: 1,
                            blurRadius: 4,
                            offset: Offset(3, 6), // changes position of shadow
                          ),
                        ],
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(55, 0, 60, 1),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30))),
                    child: ShaderMask(
                      shaderCallback: (rect) {
                        return const LinearGradient(
                          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                          begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          end: Alignment.topCenter,
                          colors: [
                            Color.fromRGBO(55, 0, 60, 0),
                            Color.fromRGBO(55, 0, 60, 1)
                          ],
                        ).createShader(
                            Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
                      },
                      blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/serie-a.png',
                        color: const Color.fromRGBO(84, 6, 87, 1),
                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 220,
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, right: 20, left: 20),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_back,
                                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            "Premier League",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.search,
                                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(top: 110, right: 20, left: 20),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      child: BackdropFilter(
                        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 30, sigmaY: 30),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          height: 220,
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                              borderRadius:
                                  const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                            height: 200,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "Premier League",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "Week 10",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                                            fontSize: 13),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                              2 -
                                          74,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                top: 8, left: 20, right: 20),
                                            child: SizedBox(
                                              height: 75,
                                              width: 70,
                                              child: Image.asset(
                                                  "assets/images/newcastle.png"),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "Newcastle  asdsadas",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 18,
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                          const Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                            child: Text(
                                              "Home",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                                  fontSize: 11),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 60,
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              "0 : 9",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                                                  fontSize: 31,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  top: 13.0),
                                              child: Container(
                                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                height: 30,
                                                width: 40,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                                          255, 40, 130, 1)
                                                      .withOpacity(0.2),
                                                  border: Border.all(
                                                      color:
                                                          const Color.fromRGBO(
                                                              255, 40, 130, 1),
                                                      width: 1),
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                                ),
                                                child: const Text(
                                                  "113'",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                          255, 40, 130, 1),
                                                      fontSize: 11),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                              2 -
                                          74,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                top: 8, left: 20, right: 20),
                                            child: SizedBox(
                                              height: 75,
                                              width: 55,
                                              child: Image.asset(
                                                  "assets/images/chelsea.png"),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "Newcastle asdfddd",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 18,
                                                color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          ),
                                          const Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                            child: Text(
                                              "Away",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                                  fontSize: 11),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, right: 20, left: 20),
                child: Container(
                  height: 400,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 20),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            child: TabBar(
                              labelPadding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                              isScrollable: true,
                              indicatorWeight: 0,
                              labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                              labelColor: Colors.white,
                              indicator: const ShapeDecoration(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(15))),
                                  color: Colors.pink),
                              tabs: const [
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Summary",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Info",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Line-up",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "H2H",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Table",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "News",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Info",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Info",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Info",
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "Info",
                                ),
                              ],
                              controller: _tabController,
                              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: TabBarView(
                            controller: _tabController,
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: const [
                                      Text("2"),
                                      Text("Shots on goal"),
                                      Text("3")
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                                    2 -
                                                36,
                                        // child: LinearPercentIndicator(
                                        //   lineHeight: 7,
                                        //   percent: 0.7,
                                        //   padding:
                                        //       const EdgeInsets.only(right: 2),
                                        //   backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                        //           255, 40, 130, 1)
                                        //       .withOpacity(0.1),
                                        //   progressColor: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                        //       255, 40, 130, 1),
                                        //   animation: true,
                                        //   animationDuration: 1000,
                                        //   barRadius: const Radius.circular(20),
                                        //   isRTL: true,
                                        // ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                                    2 -
                                                36,
                                        child: LinearPercentIndicator(
                                          padding:
                                              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2),
                                          lineHeight: 7,
                                          percent: 0.3,
                                          backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                                  255, 40, 130, 1)
                                              .withOpacity(0.1),
                                          progressColor: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                              55, 0, 60, 1),
                                          animation: true,
                                          animationDuration: 500,
                                          barRadius: const Radius.circular(20),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                              const Text("abcd"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `LinearPercentIndicator` widget is in the commented part and underneath it.

Flutter version: 3.3.3

Comment: Did you try flutter clean command? Try flutter clean, check the pubspec.yaml and make sure the package is include here at dependences and has exactly two spaces before it, then try flutter pub get again.

Comment: Yes, i already tried that. I also tried removing the package and installing it again, but it did not wok.

Comment: Can you share a GitHub repository or something similar? We at least need to see the pubspec and the file you are experiencing the issue in.

Comment: everything is working as expected

Comment: for some reason, for me it's not working

Comment: I run this code. It's run perfectly.  you try( percent_indicator: ) without any version. also, use the command "flutter clean" and then run "flutter pub get" in the terminal.

Comment: "flutter clean" and "flutter pub get" worked for me